# Deserialize data as list of objects using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Json data looking like:

```
{
  "prop1": val1,
  "prop2": val2,
  "prop3": val3,
}
{
  "prop1": val4,
  "prop2": val5,
  "prop3": val6,
}
```

Also I have a class:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("prop1")]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prop2")]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prop3")]
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to Deserialize this data like this:

```
List<RootObject> lstObjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonData);
```

But this give me an error "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly".

If I deserialize only one object like

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
```

everything works fine. I can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: @dbc Thank you. That works.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is invalid. It should look like:

```
[
    {
      "prop1": "val1",
      "prop2": "val2",
      "prop3": "val3",
    },
    {
      "prop1": "val4",
      "prop2": "val5",
      "prop3": "val6",
    }
]
```

And it works.

Comment: I understand, but I couldn't change input data.